# Passport local strategy attach validate return to @Body in nestJS

Tags: authentication, controller, nestjs, passport.js, endpoint

Basically, I have a nest application and followed the implementation of the auth module with passport following the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/recipes/passport#passport-authentication). After that, I've been doing some refactoring, adding types, etc.

One of the conventions I'm following throughout my codebase is that the controller endpoints will specify what they receive in the body of the request. eg. `async createUser(@Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto)`

The documentation endpoint for the local strategy sign in is exactly the following:

```
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(@Request() req) {
    return req.user;
  }
```

I want to change from using the `@Request()` to using `@Body()` decorator. However, I haven't been able to find how to change the `AuthGuard('local')` to return the user content to the `@Body()` specified parameter.

I have tried adding the `property` config in the authModule, eg.

```
PassportModule.register({
    property: 'signInDto',
}),
```

But it still did not work. Is there any way of achieving this, preferably, using the default passport local guard? If not, how can I achieve the desired functionality?

Answer (score 0):

i don't know if i understand you correctly or not.

you want to return the user in the body of the received request.

> However, I haven't been able to find how to change the AuthGuard('local') to return the user content to the @Body() specified parameter.

if so then you shouldn't do that the body of the request is what the user of the api sent to you.

in login request the user send you for example the email and password of his account and from that information you check if the user exist and if so you get his account.

you can use @Request and @Body in the same request like this.

```js
@UseGuards(AuthGuard('local'))
  @Post('auth/login')
  async login(@Request() req, @Body() createUserDto: CreateUserDto) {
    return doSomething(req.user);
  }
```

the local guard will return user instance if body data was valid according to your validation code.

Comment: The idea is to avoid using @Request() altogether. Although using the request directly is possible I do not think it's very descriptive, plus it deviates from the current pattern followed in the codebase.
Ideally I would be able to do something like the following: `async signin(@Body() signInDto: SignInDto)`.

Comment: I don't think you can get the signed-in user without the request instance, you need it because you are injecting the validated user instance inside it, if you can obtain the request instance without using @Request that could help you, otherwise, you need the request instance to fetch the validated user.

Comment: That is exactly my question, whether it is possible or not to get it without having to use @Request() and if it is, how to do it

Comment: you can create a service that is request scoped ([see this](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/injection-scopes)), and just inject the request instance inside it like this: `import { Injectable, Scope, Inject } from '@nestjs/common';
import { REQUEST } from '@nestjs/core';
import { Request } from 'express';

@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class CatsService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {}
}`